# How to create fixed height table in HTML and adding data dynamically without changing table layout

Tags: html

I want to create table in HTML with 10 rows. Table must be static one like below image, whether data is there or not table layout should not change. Any solutions in HTML-CSS or JS or Bootstrap-4 or PHP or Ajax are welcomed.
[image]

Comment: Your question is both broad and unclear. Creating a table with 10 rows is trivial but how it may or may not be filled in with data depends on a lot of other factors. Please [edit] your question and provide more details of what you are trying to do and what you have tried.

Comment: i want fixed length table for 10 rows. no matter how much data is coming from database, table height should not change.

Comment: Then simply loop through your data and output exactly 10 rows ... and if there are less than 10 rows output blank rows as shown in the example in the answer below.

Comment: ok bro will try that.

Answer (score 1):

Example with some added css on td with a border to show that the table rows exist:

```css
td {
border: 1px solid black
}
```

```html
<table>
<tr>
  <th>First name</th>
  <th>Last name</th>
  <th>Email</th>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>John</td>
  <td>Doe</td>
  <td>john@example.com</td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
  <td> </td>
</tr>

</table>
```

Comment: Its not for an static page, data coming from database. so i need fixed table layout because data coming from database.
but make sure PHP-MySQL data should not change the table layout.

Comment: That's going to be determined by your data, but ultimately you can limit it to 10 rows.